# Simple switch case not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is simple code to change the display of a div on the button action using switch case.
Please have a look at it i am not getting where i went wrong.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/r6nkuwvc/

javascipt code:

```
$(document).on('click', ".change", function() {
  var $input = $(this);
  $(".same").each(function() {
    if ($(this).css("display") == "block") {
      $(this).css("display", "none");
    }
  });
  switch ($input.attr("id")) {
    case "b1":
      $("#abc").css("display", "block");
      break;
    case "b2":
      $("#xyz").css("display", "block");
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: did you forget to include jquery library link in your code? check it out.

Comment: the jsfiddle works for me if I add jquery to the library and put #abc and #xyz instead of #hello and #bye. https://jsfiddle.net/r6nkuwvc/1/

Comment: @progysm i just forgot to copy paste the updated code with abc and xyz and yes i forgot to add jquery library. thnx

Comment: Use an object to store the corresponding selector... this way you can make it simple and also can avoid switch case

Comment: @geeksal yup that was the problem actually..thnx

Comment: @SudhanshuSaini see my answer

Comment: `$(document).on('click', ".change", function() {
  var sel = {
    b1: "#hello",
    b2: "bye"
  };
  $(".same").hide();
  $(sel[this.id]).show()
})`

Comment: @PranavCBalan can u please edit that in fiddle

Comment: @SudhanshuSaini : https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/r6nkuwvc/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, your code works as is. You just forgot to add the jQuery library, and the selectors `#hello` and `#bye` didn't exist. Next to that, you are also over-complicating your code. In jQuery you do not have to check if an element is visible before hiding it, you can just hide it. And when using a class selector you do not have to run `.each` against it for jQuery's own internal functions such as `hide()`; jQuery will hide all elements with this class.

https://jsfiddle.net/r6nkuwvc/5/

```
$(document).on('click', ".change", function() {
  $(".same").hide();

  switch ($(this).attr("id")) {
    case "b1":
      $("#abc").show();
      break;
    case "b2":
      $("#xyz").show();
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: yaay this one seems easy to understand thnx

Comment: will this work if i have 10 divs and all of them with display: block ? I want this space to be overwritten again and again

Comment: Yes it will, as long as the divs you want to show have the class `same`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it even much simpler using an object. Store the reference to the 
selector in an object this way you can avoid the switch case. Although use [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods to show and hide the elements.

```
// object which holds the reference
var sel = {
  b1: "#abc",
  b2: "#xyz"
};
$(document).on('click', ".change", function() {
  // hide all elements initially there is no need to iterate over them
  $(".same").hide();
  // get selector from object using id and show the element
  $(sel[this.id]).show();
})
```

```js
$(document).on('click', ".change", function() {
  var sel = {
    b1: "#abc",
    b2: "#xyz"
  };
  $(".same").hide();
  $(sel[this.id]).show();
})
```

```css
.same {
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#abc {
  display: block;
}
#xyz {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="abc" class="same">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div id="xyz" class="same">
    Bye
  </div>

  <button id="b1" class="change">b1</button>
  <br>
  <button id="b2" class="change">b2</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I like this answer. I wonder what's the fastest. An object or a switch-statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have not put up proper id's. Also I think you forget to set JQuery link in your code, that is why it is giving reference error.

Here is the updated code:

```js
$(document).on('click', ".change", function(){
 var $input = $(this);
  $(".same").each(function(){
   if($(this).css("display")=="block"){
     $(this).css("display","none");
    }
  })
  switch($input.attr("id")){
   case "b1" : $("#abc").css("display", "block");
          break;
    case "b2" : $("#xyz").css("display","block");
          break;
  }
})
```

```css
.same{
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#abc{
  display: block;
}
#xyz{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="abc" class="same">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div id="xyz" class="same">
    Bye
  </div>
  
  <button id="b1" class="change">b1</button><br>
  <button id="b2" class="change">b2</button>
</body>
```

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r6nkuwvc/6/

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to control what to show/hide from html, than I suggest this approach:

```js
$('body').on('click', '[data-hide]', function(e) {
    $($(this).data('hide')).hide();
});
$('body').on('click', '[data-show]', function(e) {
    $($(this).data('show')).show();
});
```

```css
.same {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#abc {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc" class="same">
    Hello
</div>
<div id="xyz" class="same">
    Bye
</div>
<p>
    <button data-hide=".same" data-show="#abc">Show Hallo</button>
</p>
<p>
    <button data-hide=".same" data-show="#xyz">Show Bye</button>
</p>
```